# What's the difference between the get before a method in a class and a get of a WeakMap function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know the difference between the 2 gets in the count method.
I get the same result using both.
The reason I'm using WeakMap is for making private members such as the array(arr)

**Code 1**

```
let arr = new WeakMap();

class Stack{

    constructor(){
        arr.set(this,[])
}

    count(){
        return arr.get(this).length
}

    push(arg){
        arr.get(this).push(arg)
}

    pop(){
        arr.get(this).pop()
}

    peek(){
        return arr.get(this)[arr.get(this).length-1]
}

}
```

**Code 2**

```
let arr = new WeakMap();

class Stack{

    constructor(){
        arr.set(this,[])
}

    get count(){
        return arr.get(this).length
}

    push(arg){
        arr.get(this).push(arg)
}

    pop(){
        arr.get(this).pop()
}

    peek(){
        return arr.get(this)[arr.get(this).length-1]
}

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: The first count is a plain method, the second count is a accessor property.and is added to prototype.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the same result using both

No you don't.

`get  prop() {}`

sets a getter property, from which you'll directly access its return value using `instance.prop`, while

`prop() {}`

sets a function method, that you'll have to call in order to get the return value, using `instance.prop()`.

Comment: So the main difference between the two is just how I can access it? pretty much the ()?

Comment: Well no, one is a function the other one is a number, one can be bound to an other object, the other can't etc. They are not the same, dot. Except if consider that 1 and 2 are the same because you can do 1+1 to "achieve the same result".

Comment: I have assigned both values to objects and it worked the same and I could also concatenate them. I think I misunderstood what you said. Can you give me a simple example of what you meant?

Comment: I don't get what you don't understand... `typeof class1.count !== typeof class2.count`. They are not the same. You can get the same result by **calling** `class1.count()` rather than getting `class2.count`, but you can't use the same. Say you have a function `fn(instance) => { if(instance.count <3) ... }` this function would only work with the one with the property, it wouldn't be compatible with class1's method.